# LWC trailhead SuperBage step 5

Tags: lightning-web-components, superbadges

For the selectBoat() method, This following content is not correct, could you help to let me what I have done wrong?

```
selectBoat() {

const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('boatselect', { boatId: this.boat.Id });
this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you.  You need to pass up the boatId with in the detail object rather than on it's own.

```
const searchEvent = new CustomEvent('boatselect', { detail: { boatId: this.boat.Id}});
this.dispatchEvent(searchEvent);
```

Comment: An explanation of what changed would be helpful and get you more upvotes. Consider [edit]ing your answer to include the information.